# Multiple loop issue - pull one featured and then continue the loop

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am writing a custom multiple loop to be used on a custom category template page. The loop should put one post that is checked as featured in admin, in a separate div, and continue the loop displaying all posts from the category except the featured.

Similar to the example provided on the [codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_in_Action) except I don't want to create a separate category for the featured post.

I am using Advanced Custom Fields plugin for the check box that sets posts as featured.

I have the following issue with my code: `if ($post->ID == $do_not_duplicate) continue;` prevents rest of the loop to be executed. The code below just pulls the latest featured post.

Here is my function:

```
function featured() {
$featured = new WP_Query(array(
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'featured',
        'value' => '"top"',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
'posts_per_page' => 1
));

while ( $featured->have_posts() ) : $featured -> the_post(); 
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
<div id="featured">
    //featured post
</div><!-- end #featured -->
<?php 
endwhile;
if(have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
if ($post->ID == $do_not_duplicate) continue;
?>
<div class="container">
// normal posts
</div><!-- .charities-container -->
<?php 
endwhile;
endif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;` with `$do_not_duplicate = get_the_ID();`.

After the first loop (the featured) call [`wp_reset_postdata();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata)

```
....

</div><!-- end #featured -->
<?php 
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();

if( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

...
```